# Изображение на QScene не отображается на QGraphicsView

Tags: qt

```
 QImage img(data_image, Nc, Nl, Nc, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QVector<QRgb> color_table;
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        color_table.append(qRgb(i,i,i));
    img.setColorTable(color_table);
    QImage optimal_img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB32);
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
    scene->addItem(&item);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Пытаюсь отобразить изображение таким образом, но QGraphicScene оказывается пустым. Пробовал отображать текст (`QGraphicsScene::addText`) - он отображается. Картинка не пустая, я проверил. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как проверяли картинку? Пробовали ли, например, вывести её в `QLabel`?

Comment: @alexis031182 сохранял в файл. только что попробовал в QLabel - вывелось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите `item` в вашем коде как указатель:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
scene->addItem(item);
```

После выхода из функции, в которой содержится этот код, объект уничтожается, и указатель становится невалидным. Это можно проверить, сохранив содержимое graphicsView в файл сразу после добавления image:

```
ui->graphicsView->grab().save(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/tmp.png");
```

Comment: Благодарю, теперь все отображается.

Comment: @bronstein87, если ответ Вам помог, примите его, поставив зелёную галку под стрелочками с голосами.